# Jquery validate and a list of select box

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

How Can i specific require and unique condition for a list of select box like below?

```
<form name="signupForm" class="cmxform" id="signupForm" method="get" action="">
<select name="category[]" id="cat_1">
<option value="">Select One</option>
<option value="1">aa</option>
<option value="2">bb</option>
<option value="3">cc</option>
<option value="4">dd</option>
</select>
<select name="category[]" id="cat_2">
<option value="">Select One</option>
<option value="5">ee</option>
<option value="6">ff</option>
<option value="7">gg</option>
<option value="8">hh</option>
</select>
<select name="category[]" id="cat_3">
<option value="">Select One</option>
<option value="9">ii</option>
<option value="10">jj</option>
<option value="11">kk</option>
<option value="12">ll</option>
</select>
<input class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Notice that there are the number of cat is not fixed, it can be more than 3,

so how to make it required for each selectbox,

and each selectbox chosen value must  be unique using jquery validate plugin? Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var $selects = $('form select[name^=category]'),
    values = [];

$(':submit').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  values = [];
  $($selects).each(function() {
      if($(this).val()) {
          values.push($(this).val());        
      }
  });
    if(!values.length) {
        alert('Please select all categories');
        return false;
    }
  if(values.length < $selects.length || $.unique(values).length < $selects.length) {
    alert('Please select all categories and be unique');
    return false;
  }
});
```

***[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/BbkvL/)***

Comment: @Leo Chan I don't any validation plugin.

Comment: Thanks, however, when the selection is correct , i presss confirm button and no response at all (not go to the page i post) ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a great jQuery validation plugin that will make your life easier: http://www.position-absolute.com/articles/jquery-form-validator-because-form-validation-is-a-mess/

This is all you need to do: (the plugin does the rest)

```
<select id="sport" class="validate[required]" name="sport">
<option value="">--Select--</option>
<option value="option1">Tennis</option>
<option value="option2">Football</option>
<option value="option3">Golf</option>
</select>
```

Hope that helps :)

Comment: @Sparky "and each selectbox chosen value must be unique using jquery validate plugin?" he wanted it to be implemented using a jquery plugin. The standard jQuery's Validate plugin does not accomplish this as it's buggy. So suggesting another plugin seems legit

Comment: @Aram, there is nothing buggy about requiring that each `input` element have a _unique_ name.  If you find yourself duplicating `name`'s then your HTML markup is the source of the bug.

Comment: @Sparky, it's sometimes convenient to give the same name to different selectboxes thus creating a group, which when submitted turns into an array of values, sort of.. so that's not always considered as being a buggy html

Comment: It's not a bug if you cannot conform to the markup requirements of the plugin.    However, I cannot accept a scenario where multiple input elements share the same `name` in order to _"sort of"_ create an array... surely there are better ways.

Comment: @Sparky suggest a better way then :)

Comment: @Aram, I already did.  The better way is to make sure the input elements each have a unique name.  Those can be part of an actual array as well. `name[1]`,  `name[2]`, etc.